# use of plus (+) not working in Keyup function

Tags: javascript

All set but kindly see the addition of salary here it add salary's value as html to last calculation (I think it is because of plus sign (+) as javascrip use it to add two html values)

html code: html code is perfect, just need to focus in php code

```
 <div id="addPart1" class="hide/row r/iow" style="line-height:35px; width:100%;margin:auto; min-width:800px;float:left;padding-left:20px; font-size:120%">

    <div  style="display:inline-block; width:14%">

    <input class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:30px" name="c_v[]" list="browsers" >
    <datalist id="browsers">


     <?php include 'f_select_account.php'; ?></div>


    <div  style="display:inline-block; width:14%">

    <input class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:30px" name="item[]" list="browsers" >
    <datalist id="browsers">

    <?php include 'f_select_account.php'; ?></div>

    <div  style="display:inline-block; width:14%">

  <select id="selectID1" name="usi" class="chosen-select form-control" required style="height:25px; font-size:80%">


    <?php include 'f_select_users_emp.php'; ?></div>

      <div  style="display:inline-block; width:17%"><input style="height:30px;margin-left:0px" class="form-control" type="text" id="descID1" name ="item_note[]"  form="partForm"></div>




      <div  style="text-align:right; display:inline-block; width:7%"><input  style="text-align:right; height:30px"  class="form-control coll" type="text" id="collID1" name="amount[]" form="partForm"></div>
      <div  style="text-align:right; display:inline-block; width:7%"><input  style="text-align:right; height:30px"  class="form-control per" type="text" id="perID1" name="amount[]" form="partForm"></div>
                <div  style="text-align:right;display:inline-block; width:7%"><input  style="text-align:right; height:30px"  class="form-control comm" type="text" id="amt1ID" name="amount1[]" form="partForm"></div>

      <div  style="text-align:right; display:inline-block; width:7%"><input  style="text-align:right; height:30px"  class="form-control salary" type="text" id="amtID" name="amount[]" form="partForm"></div>
      <div  style="text-align:right;display:inline-block; width:7%"><input readonly style="text-align:right; height:30px"  class="form-control tamount" type="text" id="amt1ID" name="amount1[]" form="partForm"></div>

      <div  style="display:inline-block; width:2%"><input  STYLE="cursor:pointer; width:100%; text-align:right; font-size:140%; font-weight:bold; border:none; background:none" id="deleteLine1" value="X" /></div>


    </div>



    <div style=" back/ground:whitesmoke; width:100%;margin:auto;padding-left:20px ">
      <a href='javascript:void(0);' STYLE="font-size:140%; text-decoration:none; border:none; background:none; color:brown"  id="addLine">add row <i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>





    </div>

</div>
```

php code: here the issue salary is not being added to the rest of formula... Multiplication (*) and minus (-) is working but plus (+) working not properly .. it work as htmls value addiiton.

```
 $('body').delegate('.coll,.per,.comm, .salary, 
  .tamount','keyup',function()
                {
                    var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
                    var coll =tr.find('.coll').val();
                    var per =tr.find('.per').val();



                    var amt =(coll * per / 100);



                    tr.find('.comm').val(amt);
                    var salary =tr.find('.salary').val();
                     var tamt =(coll * per / 100 + salary); 

                    tr.find('.tamount').val(tamt);




                });
            });
```

Comment: `var tamt =(((coll * per) / 100) + salary);` try using proper braces.

Comment: @deepeshkumar - that's an overuse of unnecessary *bracket* - in fact, it should be `var tamt = coll * per / 100 + salary;` - no braces **at all**

Comment: Delegate is deprecated, use "on()"

Comment: `var salary = +tr.find('.salary').val();` should fix it - because `val()` returns a string, and `+ string` coerces the values to strings ..

Comment: Slight correction, braces are `{` and `}`. Parentheses are `(` and `)` :D

Comment: I wasn't being pedantic - I was correcting an incorrect correction - and in maths, it's a *bracket* anyway - hence BODMAS

Comment: @Prime Burg, why do you think "+" is causing problems?

Comment: @KillerDeath not working properly. Yes if we use muliply * then it works......

Answer (score 0):

I got solution as plus is not working but other operators working so I use minus (-) and -1*(salary)

var tamt =(coll * per / 100 - (-salary);

so it solved but need to get info about why plus sign not working and why t works as to add as html values.